# Dotnet 7 EventLog - Log to Applications and services instead of Windows Logs Applications

Tags: c#, windows-services, .net-6.0, event-log, .net-7.0

I tried to log via Windows Service created in dotnet 7.
I have appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    },
    "EventLog": {
      "SourceName": "TestSourceName",
      "LogName": "TestSourceNameLogs",
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Information",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and registrations in Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog;
using TestSourceName.QueueWorker;
using System.Diagnostics;

HostApplicationBuilder builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddWindowsService(options =>
{
    options.ServiceName = "TestSourceName";
});

// For creating source and logs
//if (!EventLog.SourceExists("TestSourceName")) EventLog.CreateEventSource("TestSourceName", //"TestSourceNameLogs");

builder.Logging.ClearProviders();

LoggerProviderOptions.RegisterProviderOptions<EventLogSettings, EventLogLoggerProvider>(builder.Services);

builder.Services.AddHostedService<WindowsBackgroundService>();
builder.Logging.AddEventLog(eventLogSettings =>
{
    eventLogSettings.LogName = "TestSourceNameLogs";
    eventLogSettings.SourceName = "TestSourceName";
});
builder.Logging.AddConfiguration(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));

IHost host = builder.Build();
host.Run();
```

The service is logging always in Windows Logs Applications not in Applications ans services => TestSourceNameLogs, but the TestSourceNameLogs exists and is empty.
Please help me to find the mistake.